# Drupal pager on table with sort and select and search not working

Tags: php, select, drupal-7, pagination

I have a query which I want shown as a Drupal tableselect with sorting and pagination and search term which is memorized in the $_SESSION. The problem is that the pagination is not working.

My code looks kinda like this:

```
//build the header row (except the checkbox)
    $header = array(
      'status' => array('data' => t('Status')),
      'name' => array('data' => t('Product name'), 'field' => 'p.name'),
      'actions' => array('data' => t('Actions'))
    );

 //do the query for the data
    $query = db_select('my_products', 'p');
    $query->addField('p', 'pid');
    $query->addField('p', 'name');
    $query->addField('p', 'status');
    //in case there is a search term then filter the table
    if(isset($_SESSION['search_term_product'])) {
        $query->condition('p.name', '%' . db_like($_SESSION['search_term_product']) . '%', 'LIKE');
    }
    //add a pager to the resulting data and a sorter
    $query->extend('PagerDefault')
        ->limit(10);
        ->extend('TableSort')
        ->orderByHeader($header);
    $result_set = $query->execute();

    //structure the data accordingly
    $rows = array();
    $default_value = array();
    foreach($result_set as $product) {
        $default_value[$product->pid] = $product->status == 1 ? TRUE : FALSE; //ticked or not tiked
        $rows[$product->pid] = array(//array key is needed for form submission
          'status' => $product->status == 1 ? t('Active') : t('Not active'),
          'name' => array(
            'data' => array(
              '#type' => 'link',
              '#title' => $product->name,
              '#href' => $base_url . '/' . $product->name . '/edit'
            )
          ),
          'actions' => array(
            'data' => array(
              '#type' => 'link',
              '#title' => 'Delete',
              '#href' => $base_url . '/' . $product->name . '/delete'
            )
          )
        );
    }

    //configure the table
    $form['products'] = array
      (
      '#type' => 'tableselect',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#options' => $rows,
      '#empty' => t('No products found'),
      '#multiple' => TRUE, //TRUE -> checkboxes FALSE-> radio buttons
      '#default_value' => $default_value,
      '#markup' => theme('pager')
    );

    $form['submit'] = array
      (
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => t('Change status'),
    );

    return $form;
```

I tried lots of solutions and searched the web extensively but I don't know why the pagination isn't working. This code just shows all the result like my pagination code wasn't even there.

Any suggestions?

Edit: In my original code I have a few joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many many tries I managed to solve it. I think there's a problem if you add the `->extend('PagerDefault')` after a join. Anyway all you have to do is change

`db_select('my_products', 'p');`

to

`db_select('my_products','p')->extend('PagerDefault')->extend('TableSort');`

```
$query->extend('PagerDefault')
        ->limit(10);
        ->extend('TableSort')
        ->orderByHeader($header);
```

to

```
$query->limit(10)
            ->orderByHeader($header);
```

delete the line with `'#markup' => theme('pager')` and before `return $form` add

```
$form['pager'] = array(
      '#markup' => theme('pager')
    );
```